# BizTalk - Catch EndPoint Not found Exception

Tags: exception, biztalk

The WCF service to which my send & receive ports are configured, is not available; thus I am getting an EndPoint not found exception. How do I catch this exception in the middle of my orcehstration and flow towards a clean exit from the orchestration? I should be able to capture the detail and invoke a class lib (through Expression shape).

I tried catching the FaultContract, System.Exception in the scope from which I am sending the request to port. But in vain.

Answer (score 0):

Your have to play by the rules first!

In order to catch an exception within your scope block in Biztalk while using a WCF request-response port, you might have to do the following...

1. Set the retry-count to 0 on your physical request-response port which you use to bind.
2. Enable the flag Delivery Notification to 'Transmitted' on your logical request-response port within the orchestration.
3. Catch the "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException" exception and handle it as your please.

Hope this helps.

References: Have a look at my article in code project [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/biztalk/ExceptionDemo.aspx)